# How to add LinkGenerator to ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

How do I add a `LinkGenerator` object to my `IServiceCollection` for DI in the Startup.cs `ConfigureServices` method?

```cs
public MyService(LinkGenerator linkGenerator) { }
```

Have tried:

```cs
public static void AddLinkGenerator(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
    services.AddScoped<IUrlHelper, UrlHelper>(implementationFactory =>
    {
        var actionContext = implementationFactory.GetService<IActionContextAccessor>().ActionContext;
        return new UrlHelper(actionContext);
    });
}
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: This was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56653105/cant-figure-out-how-to-inject-linkgenerator and it looks like the answer would work, but there are prerequisites the only answer didn't explain (like how to inject `IHttpContextAccessor`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, the LinkGenerator servides will be registered when you call the `services.AddRouting();` methods and this codes will be called when you run                 `.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });` in the program.cs methods.

So if you use configure the asp.net core application as a web host, there is no need to call  `services.AddRouting();` methods again in your ConfigureServices method. This service will be registered before startup.cs's ConfigureServices method.

You could refer to below [source codes](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/1c126ab773059d6a5899fc29547cb86ed49c46bf/src/Http/Routing/src/DependencyInjection/RoutingServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) to know how it has been registerd in RoutingServiceCollectionExtensions class.

Notice: Since the DefaultLinkGenerator is internal class, we couldn't use  `services.TryAddSingleton<LinkGenerator, DefaultLinkGenerator>();` to just register the LinkGenerator class.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddRouting(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
          //....
         // Link generation related services
        services.TryAddSingleton<LinkGenerator, DefaultLinkGenerator>();
        services.TryAddSingleton<IEndpointAddressScheme<string>, EndpointNameAddressScheme>();
        services.TryAddSingleton<IEndpointAddressScheme<RouteValuesAddress>, RouteValuesAddressScheme>();
        services.TryAddSingleton<LinkParser, DefaultLinkParser>();

          //....
     }
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!
In addition to services.AddRouting() I also needed to add calls to services.AddLogging() and services.AddOptions() to add all the required pre-requisites.